# WSO2 EI - LDAP Connector - Accessing binary attribute userPassword

Tags: wso2, openldap, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using the WSO2 LDAP Connector to get details about an LDAP entity that is of type securityObject. Is it possible to get the value of the binary userPassword attribute field. Right now I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.wso2.carbon.connector.ldap.SearchEntry.prepareNode(SearchEntry.java:111)
```

I am aware that the userPassword returns a byte array and it seems that without changing the Connector implementation there's no other possible way to retrieve the value of a binary field using the WSO2 LDAP Connector.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't encrypted. It is hashed. You can retrieve it by adding `;binary` to the attribute name, but it won't do you any good. The correct way to check a password in LDAP is to attempt to bind with it.

Comment: Thanks EJP however it seems like adding `;binary` makes the WSO2 LDAP connector look for the `userPassword;binary` field which does not exist so it returns nothing.